# Time Complexity of Separate Equal Length Arrays

Tags: python, performance, time-complexity

Just wondering what the time complexity of the below algorithm is.

```
Y = [3, 2, 1]
F = [4, 5, 6]
V = [50, 8, 1]

def algo(Y, F, V):

    sums = set({})

    for i in Y:
        for j in F:
            sums.add(i + j)

    for i in V:
        for j in sums:
            if i == j:
                return True

    return False
```

I assume its n^2, but just want to be sure... and know why it isn't if it isn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`sums` is at most size n^2, so the below nested loops is actually worst case looping through n^3 elements. Therefore `algo` actually runs in O(n^3).